# Keras lstm input and output shape

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I am new to python, deep learning and keras. I known many people asked similar questions before and i tried to read through them but my issues is still not solve. could someone please give me a hand

I want to build a 6 inputs and 1 output model. below are my codes. your help or hint will be truly appreciated.

input and output shape:

```
print(x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
```

output:

```
(503, 6) (503, 1)
```

model codes:

```
inputList={}
lstmList={}
for i in range (x_train.shape[1]):
  inputList[varList[i]]=Input(shape=(x_train.shape[0], 1), name=varList[i])  
  lstmList[varList[i]]=LSTM(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=None, dropout=0.2)(inputList[varList[i]])

z=concatenate([lstmList[i] for i in varList])
output=Dense(next_number_prediction, activation='softmax')(z)
model = Model(inputs=[inputList[i] for i in varList], outputs=[output])
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

the output is:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
open (InputLayer)               (None, 503, 1)       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
high (InputLayer)               (None, 503, 1)       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
low (InputLayer)                (None, 503, 1)       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
close (InputLayer)              (None, 503, 1)       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
change (InputLayer)             (None, 503, 1)       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pct (InputLayer)                (None, 503, 1)       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_7 (LSTM)                   (None, 64)           16896       open[0][0]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_8 (LSTM)                   (None, 64)           16896       high[0][0]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_9 (LSTM)                   (None, 64)           16896       low[0][0]                        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_10 (LSTM)                  (None, 64)           16896       close[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_11 (LSTM)                  (None, 64)           16896       change[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_12 (LSTM)                  (None, 64)           16896       pct[0][0]                        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 384)          0           lstm_7[0][0]                     
                                                                 lstm_8[0][0]                     
                                                                 lstm_9[0][0]                     
                                                                 lstm_10[0][0]                    
                                                                 lstm_11[0][0]                    
                                                                 lstm_12[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 1)            385         concatenate_1[0][0]              
==================================================================================================
Total params: 101,761
Trainable params: 101,761
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Data treatment and model.fit:

```
Data={}    
for i in range (x_train.shape[1]):
  Data[varList[i]]=np.expand_dims(x_train[:, i], axis=0)
  Data[varList[i]]=np.reshape(Data[varList[i]], (1,x_train.shape[0],1))

model.fit(
    [Data[i] for i in varList], 
    [y_train], 
    epochs=10)
```

and the error is

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-392e0052f15a> in <module>()
      1 model.fit(
      2     [Data[i] for i in varList],
----> 3     [y_train], 
            epochs=10)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
   1534         steps_name='steps_per_epoch',
   1535         steps=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1536         validation_split=validation_split)
   1537 
   1538     # Prepare validation data.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split)
    990         x, y, sample_weight = next_element
    991     x, y, sample_weights = self._standardize_weights(x, y, sample_weight,
--> 992                                                      class_weight, batch_size)
    993     return x, y, sample_weights
    994 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_weights(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size)
   1167       # Check that all arrays have the same length.
   1168       if not self._distribution_strategy:
-> 1169         training_utils.check_array_lengths(x, y, sample_weights)
   1170         if self._is_graph_network and not context.executing_eagerly():
   1171           # Additional checks to avoid users mistakenly using improper loss fns.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in check_array_lengths(inputs, targets, weights)
    424                      'the same number of samples as target arrays. '
    425                      'Found ' + str(list(set_x)[0]) + ' input samples '
--> 426                      'and ' + str(list(set_y)[0]) + ' target samples.')
    427   if len(set_w) > 1:
    428     raise ValueError('All sample_weight arrays should have '

ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 503 target samples.
```

The feed input and output dimension

```
print (Data[varList[i]].shape)
print (np.array([Data[i] for i in varList]).shape)
print (y_train.shape)
```

output:

```
(1, 503, 1)
(6, 1, 503, 1)
(503, 1)
```

tried new codes:

```
input = Input(shape=(x_train.shape))
lstm = LSTM(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2)(input)
output = Dense(1)(lstm)
model2 = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
model2.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model2.fit(x_train[np.newaxis,:,:], y_train[np.newaxis,:,:])
```

gives a untrained model:

```
Epoch 1/10
1/1 [==============================] - 4s 4s/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 385ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 387ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 386ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 390ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 390ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 390ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 389ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 387ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 10/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 391ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - acc: 0.0000e+00
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f4c97583e80>
```

where the max and min of the data are:

```
print (max(y_train), x_train.max(axis=0))
print (min(y_train), x_train.min(axis=0))
```

output:

```
[0.79951533] [0.79930947 0.79750822 0.79934846 0.79951533 0.72939786 0.99697845]
[0.19443386] [1.94643871e-01 1.96481512e-01 1.94604099e-01 1.94433856e-01
 2.52289062e-04 3.70721060e-01]
```

Comment: instead of `[y_train]`, can you try with `np.array(y_train)`

Comment: Hi Upasana 
the y_trian is already a np array (anyway, i tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work)

Comment: Is there a specific reason you use 6 input layers with the shape (None, 503, 1)? It is much more common to have 1 input layer with the shape (None, 503, 6) instead and connect this to a single lstm layer. That would simplify your network a lot.

Comment: Also: You have a sequence length of 503 right now. You also have 503 labels. So it looks like you want to predict a label for every step of your sequence. But your network only outputs one value for the whole sequence. Can you explain how your data looks like and what your goal is?

Comment: Hi  sietschie, i tried (None, 506, 6) before and that didn't even lead me to the model.summary step that time. what i want to achieve from the data is to predict the next timestep based on the historic data (but at some stage later i want to predict the next 3 timestep )

Comment: Regarding the additional information from your answer below: I think that is the point where one would need additional information about the task and the data. But a good starting point is always to start with an simplified input to test, if the network itself works as expected and then work your way towards more complex samples. And of course it is always possible that the labels simply cannot be infered from the data. So also keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Your network expects only a single label for the whole sequence. If I adapt the code like this it runs:

```
model.fit(
      [Data[i] for i in varList],
      [y_train[0:1]],
      epochs=10)
```

Of course you need to decide whether this reflects your attention or whether you need to restructure your network so it accepts one label for every element in the sequence.

By the way: This is how I would have constructed the network. So if you are new to this, maybe this is the architecture that you actually want:

```
input = Input(shape=(x_train.shape))
lstm = LSTM(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2)(input)
output = Dense(1)(lstm)
model2 = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
model2.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model2.fit(x_train[np.newaxis,:,:], y_train[np.newaxis,:,:])
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sietschie.  I tried your first suggestion, the model has 0 loss and 0 accuracy, may be i still did something wrong.  

 if i try your second suggestion, what dimensions  of the x_train and y_train the model would expect?

Comment: I still have error with your second suggestion

<pre><print (x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
(503, 6) (503, 1)>